# ARP table does not populate if computer has two IPs on same inteface

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, arp

I have three devices connected to a simple switch. All of the three devices have two IP addresses: one static (172) and one from the DHCP server (192).

Computer A: 172.16.0.1, 192.168.0.1
Computer B: 172.16.0.2, 192.168.0.2
Computer C: 172.16.0.3, 192.168.0.3

My problem is that both B and C can ping to both the IP addresses of A, but B can't ping to the 172 IP address of C (and vice versa). If the MAC address is listed in /proc/net/arp on B, I can ping to C and back (which of course makes sense).

I configure the 172 IP address as:

```bsh
$ ip addr add 172.16.0.1/16 brd 172.16.255.255 label eth0:static scope link dev eth0
$ ip route add default dev eth0 metric 1002 scope link
```

How can I make sure that when the DHCP server on A is enabled, without enabling router like services (or other services) on either A or C, everything can be reached from B?

**I've tried:**

```bsh
# Computer A
$ tcpdump
21:09:40.398635 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.1 tell 192.168.0.2, length 46
21:09:40.398668 ARP, Reply 192.168.0.1 is-at 84:7b:eb:21:80:08 (oui Unknown), length 28
21:09:40.558658 IP 192.168.0.2 > 172.16.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 2, seq 97, length 64
21:09:41.598995 IP 192.168.0.2 > 172.16.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 2, seq 98, length 64
```

```bsh
# Computer B
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c0:7a:07:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.2/16 brd 172.16.255.255 scope link eth0:static
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2c0:7aff:fe07:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
$ ip route get 172.16.0.3
172.16.0.3 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  table eth0  src 192.168.0.2 
    cache 
$ ip r
default dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
172.16.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.0.2 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.2 
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     1002   0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

```bsh
# Computer C
$ tcpdump
16:54:59.881699 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 8000.00:05:1a:a4:58:c0.8002, length 43
16:55:01.878932 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 8000.00:05:1a:a4:58:c0.8002, length 43
16:55:03.879424 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 8000.00:05:1a:a4:58:c0.8002, length 43
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:6c:8b:c0:20:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.3/16 brd 172.16.255.255 scope link eth0:static
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.3/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::826c:8bff:fec0:20f0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
$ ip route get 172.16.0.2
172.16.0.2 dev eth0  src 172.16.0.3 
    cache 
$ ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
default dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
172.16.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.0.3
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.3 
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     1002   0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

In addition (thanks to Hauke) it seems that the ICMP reply is sent to A instead of back to C.

After the fix Hauke gave in his comment, the route on B looks like:

```bsh
$ ip route get 172.16.0.3
172.16.0.3 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  table eth0  src 192.168.0.2 
    cache
```

Comment: What are the outputs of `ip a` and `ip route get 172.16.0.2` on computer C? What do you mean by "the additional IP address"?

Comment: I've updated the question with the content you've asked for. The 'additional IP address' should be the 172 address. Hope this clarifies it for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a misunderstanding I did not ask you for the output of `ip r` but this seems to make clear at least part of the problem:

```
$ ip route get 172.16.0.3
172.16.0.3 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  table eth0  src 192.168.0.2 
    cache
```

There is no route for the link-local network 172.16.0.0/16 on computer B. Thus it should send packets for 172.16.0.3 to 192.168.0.1 (thus ARP for 192.168.0.1 (if not cached) but not for 172.16.0.3). Adding the ARP entry manually should not change that. But maybe setting that also sets the route.

Computer C should be able to send a packet to B but B would try to send the response through A where it probably gets dropped.

In addition your command

```
ip route add default dev eth0 metric 1002 scope link
```

does not make any sense to me because it does not contain an address for the next hop.

And there is no need for setting `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` (at least not from what you have told in your question).

Comment: You're correct about the ICMP reply (and probably my senseless commands as well). I've added the output of `route -n` and `ip r`. Hopefully you can direct me towards a solution, because I really am lost at this point.

Comment: The `default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0` is missing on computer B. You should make sure that B and C have the same routing configuration and then reboot both. If A is the gateway then `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` (or rather the permanent configuration in `/etc/sysctl.d/`) is needed there. I am surprised that there are routes for 172 and 192 on B now. Did you change anything? Is the `ip route get 172.16.0.3` output different now?

Comment: You are a legit hero!